# Sending byte[] representing zip file from one API to another

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api, encoding, decoding

I am trying to send a zip file I create in one API (lets call this 'API 1') to another (aka 'API 2').

Originally I attempted to just send the byte[] as the response in API 1 but when accessing the response within API 2, the byte[] was a different size and the file was corrupt. I then attempted to convert the byte[] in API 1 to a base64 string and then decode in API 2, but realised the strings were not the same and again, the file was corrupt.

Here is my code as it currently stands...

## API 1 Code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult BuildZipFile(Custom myObject)
{
    CODE HERE WHICH GENERATES ZIP FILE
    byte[] zipFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ZIP FILE PATH);
    return Ok(Convert.ToBase64String(zipFile));
}
```

## API 2 Code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RetrieveZipFile(Custom myObject)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(@"https://localhost:44323/api/ProcessBuild");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject), ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    byte[] retrievedZipFile = Convert.FromBase64String(response.Content);
    return File(retrievedZipFile, "application/zip", process.Name + ".zip");
}
```

Currently this returns a zip file which is corrupt. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing you are using RestSharp and not the .NET Framework HttpClient? It seems you are sending the file the wrong way. I found this example: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/RestSharp/RestRequest/AddFile/php-restrequest-addfile-method-examples.html

Comment: In API you are returning a string, by converting it to base 64, yet your signature says byte[]

Comment: @mortb This seems to be attaching a file to a request. I am trying to send it as a response and receive it.

Comment: @AnilGoel Good spot! I have updated the post now, this was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the mime type. This should work fine. I am not familiar with RestSharp.

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath), "application/zip");
    }
```

Comment: The file will be in memory at the point of presenting back to the user (in API 2). Therefore I will not have a filePath to provide.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_Byte___System_String_

Comment: @unknownpresense ok i see now what you are saying. Why split the request though? Also you can pass a full object to the controller action, you can pass the path. Please see docs for more info for `return File()`;.